# string.format variable number of arguments

Tags: lua, string-formatting

Luas string.format is pretty straight forward, if you know what to format.
However, I stuck at writing a function which takes a wildcard-string to format, and a variable number of arguments to put into that blank string.

Example:

```
str = " %5s %3s %6s %6s", 
val = {"ttyS1", "232", "9600", "230400"}
```

Formatting that by hand is pretty easy:

```
string.format( str, val[1], val[2], val[3], val[4] )
```

Which is the same as:

```
string.format(" %5s %3s %6s %6s", "ttyS1, "232", "9600","230400")
```

But what if I wan't to have a fifth or sixth argument?
For example:

```
 string.format(" %1s %2s %3s %4s %5s %6s %7s %", ... )
```

How can I implement a string.format with an variable number of arguments?

I want to avoid appending the values one by one because of performance issues.
The application runs on embedded MCUs.

Comment: `str:format(unpack(val))`

Comment: That easy... If you put it in an answer, I can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generate arbitrary number of repeats of whatever format you want with `string.rep` if format is the same for all arguments. Or fill table with all formats and use `table.concat`. Remember that you don't need to specify index of argument in format if you don't want to reorder them.

If you just need to concatenate strings together separated by space, use more suitable tool: `table.concat(table_of_strings, ' ')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table using varargs:

```
function foo(fmt, ...)
    local t = {...}
    return t[6] -- might be nil
end
```

Ps, don't use `#` on the table if you expect the argument list might contain `nil`. Instead use `select("#", ...)`.